# Python - while loop returns print across?

Tags: python, loops

how do I make the result below print on a single line instead of down the column? Thanks.

```
i = 3
while not i<=0:
    i-=1
    print(i)
```

expected:
2 1 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 3
while not i<=0:
    i-=1
    print(i, end = ' ')
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
2 1 0
```